# C array print as tree

Tags: c, arrays

I've to create a tree containing hexadecimal values using a function which will return it. The user inputs a height, for example for 5, and it's looking like this:

```
    0
   123
  45678
 9ABCDEF
012345678
```

And this is my code so far:

```
void draw(int n) {
    char table[] = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
        printf("%X", table[i] & 0x0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no attempt to use the input, no explanation of what you are doing or how it goes wrong. That looks like you just want someone to write the code for you, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: Hint: the tree is bidimensional (it has a height and a width), and your code has only one loop on i.

Comment: But I'm trying to do that but I've a problem. I've given here my code so far, maybe you've any ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: not sure what the point of `table` is? if you do `printf("%X",i)` you'd get the same results.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Grats, you did his homework for him. Now we will all have more horrible software to use 10 years from now. :P

Comment: @Dan In ten years from now it is probably that AI is writing a program, not a person.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Who will write the AI?

Comment: @Dan AI will write on my own by 10 years.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Don't hide your answer in a link in a comment. Answer the question in an answer if you want, but consider that just providing the solution doesn't really help in a case like this.

Comment: In my future forecast, such Q will be deleted in the near future. Because both Q and A are of little value.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: nope.dadasdasdada

Answer (score 1):

Try this . .

```
void draw(int n)
{
   int i, j, k , space , letter = -1 , x = 0;
   char hexa[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        space = n-i ; // calculating spaces will be printed 
        letter += 2 ; // calculating letters will be printed 

        for(j=0;j<space;j++) printf(" ");
        for(k=0;k<letter;k++,x++) printf("%c",hexa[x%16]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```